# Is there any replacement or alternative way for using scala.collection.TraversableOnce.mkString() method in java 7

Tags: java, scala, java-7

I am able to use mkString method in scala successfully. But while trying to do it with java, there does not exist mkString method for java7. So is there any way by which i can do the same thing in java.

Below is my code for reference:

```
val records: util.List[Tuple2[Void, Array[AnyRef]]] = dataSource.collect
    import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
    for (record <- records) {
      println(record.f1.mkString(","))
    }
```

Comment: What is `f1`? Prefer `JavaConverters`. Otherwise it should just work to convert java list to scala collection and use mkString.

Comment: org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2 takes two vaues in the tuple. As given in the above code:
        Tuple2[Void, Array[AnyRef]]

 To access the first value we use f0 and to access the value of second part (Array[AnyRef]) we use f1.

I tried using JavaConverters. But the problem still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Arrays.deepToString` to get the string representation of your array elements.

```
 List<Tuple2<Void, Object[]>> records= dataSource.collect();
   Tuple2<Void, Object[]> record = records.iterator().next();
   System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(record.f1));
```